# Best way to display realtime queue data from database in grid

Tags: sql-server, winforms, performance, data-binding

I have a client-server VB.NET/SQL2008 application which, among other things, keeps track of people who are waiting in a queue.  The records for the queue are all updated via the application but they are added/removed on different workstations.

I need to display the queue of people in a grid (could do a multi column listbox if it would add any benefit) and have it automagically update when the queue changes.  I don't need it to be real-real-time but I would like the people to show up within a few seconds.  I currently have a datagrid bound to the data and I have a timer which is refreshing the datagrid every few seconds.  However I'm thinking there must be a better way to do it.

The one thing I don't like is how the grid flickers when it refreshes and if someone double-clicks to select a record exactly as it's refreshing it selects the first person in the list and not the one selected.

I've done some research and it seems like one option is SQL Dependency - however from what I've seen people say it's difficult to set up and get working and "fragile".

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, at the end of reading your question I forgot that little detail CLIENT-SERVER